# How can I publish a page by using PowerShell

Tags: publishing, powershell

How can I publish a page by leveraging PowerShell, instead of building yet another C# console application?

*This is a practical theoretical question, based on [Timer Jobs in Tridion](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/timer-jobs-in-tridion/4229#4229).*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Publish from PowerShell?](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/how-to-publish-from-powershell)

Comment: @SivaCharan: Similar title, different question. I do not think it is a duplicate.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I'm not sure if it offers much beyond "how can I publish using the core service", but closing it as a duplicate wouldn't be correct.

Answer (score 5):

A few lines of PowerShell can do the trick and is a powerful toy for automated administrative tasks.

1: Install Tridion Powershell Modules. See the [project on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-powershell-modules/) to download the module and [these setup instructions](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3643/88).

2: Get the page URI and PublishTarget URI.

3: Run a script like this. This will get you a CoreService client (this is the part which uses the Tridion PowerShell Modules), create a PublishInstruction, and publish a page (tcm:69-6164-64) to a target(tcm:0-1-65537).

```
Set-TridionCoreServiceSettings cms.server.com 2013-SP1
$client = Get-TridionCoreServiceClient

$resolveInstruction = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ResolveInstructionData
$renderInstruction = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.RenderInstructionData
$publishIntructionData = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.PublishInstructionData
$publishIntructionData.RenderInstruction = $renderInstruction
$publishIntructionData.ResolveInstruction = $resolveInstruction
$readOptions = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ReadOptions

$client.Publish("tcm:69-6164-64", $publishIntructionData, "tcm:0-1-65537", 
    [Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.PublishPriority]::Normal, $readOptions)
```